# Merging dataframes based on lists of row numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to compare every row with every row in large dataframes (> 50000) leading to over 1 billion comparisons which is too computationally expensive on Pandas dataframes.

Therefore I load my values into arrays and compare it using generators:

```
start = df['StartPos'].values.tolist()
end = df['EndPos'].values.tolist()
index = df.index.values.tolist()
a = [(y-x, (i,j)) for i,x in enumerate(start) for j,y in enumerate(end) if (y-x) > 0 and (y-x) <= 2000 and i != j]
if len(a) == 0:
    continue
prod_sizes, rows = zip(*a)
row1,row2 = zip(*rows)
```

Now, for every dataframe `df` I end up with a list like

```
>>> row1
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
>>> row2
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Now I want to merge my original dataframe `df` based on the values of `row1` and `row2`. The output dataframe should look like:

```
0:   columns of row0 | columns of row1
1:   columns of row0 | columns of row2
2:   columns of row0 | columns of row3
3:   columns of row0 | columns of row4
4:   columns of row0 | columns of row5
5:   columns of row1 | columns of row2
6:   columns of row1 | columns of row3
...
15:  columns of row4 | columns of row5
```

Is there a Pandas-way to do this merge operation based on lists of row numbers, or should I simply use loops and access rows via .iloc and append them to a new dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by `compare`? check if they're equal?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a key help for expand grid merge

For example you have below dataframe

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]})
```

We doing the `merge` with `assign` the key

```
mergedf=df1.assign(key=1).reset_index().merge(df2.assign(key=1).reset_index(),on='key')
mergedf.loc[mergedf.index_y>mergedf.index_x] # filter out the row in df1 greater than row in df2

Out[497]: 
   index_x  A_x  key  index_y  A_y
1        0    1    1        1    2
2        0    1    1        2    3
5        1    2    1        2    3
```